# replay animation CSS3 every 3 seconds

Tags: css, css-animations

I made an animation css3 however need to be run every 3 seconds infinite, unable to do only with css.

CSS3

```
.halo-robford-animate{
    animation: leaves 0.3s ease-in-out 3 alternate;
    -webkit-animation: leaves 0.3s ease-in-out 3 alternate;
}
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/ctoveloz/pen/Hiovw)

Comment: Googled the answer in 10 seconds. You should try harder

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `animation-iteration-count`. The formal syntax for `animation` is:

```
animation: <single-animation-name> || <time> || <timing-function> || <time> || <single-animation-iteration-count> || <single-animation-direction> || <single-animation-fill-mode>
```

[**Source + additional info**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation)

You could change it to:

```
.halo-robford-animate{
    animation: leaves 0.3s ease-in-out 3s infinite alternate;
    -webkit-animation: leaves 0.3s ease-in-out 3s infinite alternate;
     -moz-animation: leaves 0.3s ease-in-out 3s infinite alternate;
    -o-animation: leaves 0.3s ease-in-out 3s infinite alternate;
}
```

Note the measurement of `3` requires a unit, so added an `s` to make it `3s`. The second time measurement is the `animation-delay` which specifies the delay in which it will start, not between animations.

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KwDiB)

Or use the properties individually:

```
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
```

If you want a 3 second gap between the animations where the animation takes 0.3s, you'll need to make a slight adjustment. Change the `animation-duration` to `3s` (which is the `0.3s` you have)

```
.halo-robford-animate{
    animation: leaves 3s ease-in-out 3s infinite alternate;
    -webkit-animation: leaves 3s ease-in-out 3s infinite alternate;
     -moz-animation: leaves 3s ease-in-out 3s infinite alternate;
    -o-animation: leaves 3s ease-in-out 3s infinite alternate;
}
```

And make animation only occur for the first 0.3s:

```
@-webkit-keyframes leaves {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    5% {
      opacity: 0.5;
    }

    10% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

[**Demo 2**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hAmHn)

Answer (score 0):

Try and add this to your code

```
.halo-robford-animate{
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```